# competiveness in studies

Tags: allah, source-identification, sin, islamic-basis, helping

I want to be first in studies and likes to be ineverything as possible.I somehow know it is permissile..but i want to know that  is it encouraged in islam?..beacuse in case of competiting like studies and all, we want to keep our plans ,strategies and also any kind of notes,or resources all that in secrets and we tend to hide that from competitors...is that a good thing...will allah gets happy if we hide all these..is it encouraged?..or should i help them as helping is encouraged in islam ...but if i not help ..will allah does not get happy..and should i help them even if they dont ask for ?if that was the case ,how can I expect to be first than them? i got so many waswas like this.. and also sometimes i think when Im done wrng..i'ii be like allah will not happy with me thats all..and there is no hope for me..also allah will punish me in any  ways in this world..how to get rid of that?..please clear my doubts..

Comment: Do you know difference between hasad and rashq ?